# PHPMailer and DKIM, SPF validation with an authenticated SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, spf

I have a web application with email notifications.
I'm using PHPMailer to send mails over authenticated SMTP by the SMTP server given by my provider.

All messages are invalidated by SPF and DKIM settings because somehow it is expected that my webserver is included in the SPF list and PHPMailer has to sign the message.

Is there any way to let the the SMTP server to envelope and sign the email for me?
I tought an authenticated SMTP connection will define the first server as enveloped-by and not the first client. Is this a wrong tought or a misconfiguration of the SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

Whether your mail server will DKIM-sign for you is up to the mail server – and it is generally preferable to do that as you don't then have to worry about it.

However, it is definitely better to sign it yourself if you can. If you're sending through your hosting provider's mail server, they would need to have access to your private key in order to be able to sign as your domain. For this reason, if they do sign, it is often as an intermediary rather than as the original sender, and this may mean they can't vouch for the `From` address which you would need to be signed to pass DMARC checks. You can do both at once, because it's entirely legitimate for a message to contain multiple DKIM signatures, signed at different points of the message's journey, by different parties.

SPF does include the originating IP, but you need to be aware of the difference between "regular" SMTP and the SMTP submission protocol defined in [RFC6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409), and specifically mentions that you might expect a submission server to [add a signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409#section-8.5). Submission clients will often *not* be treated as the origin (from an SPF perspective). If that server is in your own network, then you have no issues with holding private keys.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But how can I understand what is the considered "origin" from SPF point of view? In other words, how can I recognize the client from the first submission server from message headers?

Comment: The chain will be visible in `received` headers, but you may find that the first one listed is the submission server rather than the client; I’m not certain on the exact rules surrounding this.